# How does connection pooling work on IIS?

Tags: iis, load-balancing, application-pools

How does IIS connection pooling work, especially in clustered environments (with load balancing, and databases in the backend)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another [friend](http://twitter.com/kangelos) recommended [this](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;169470) document.

Comment: Damn. This document no exist no more.

Comment: Here: http://web.archive.org/web/20110420043538/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/169470